# Chinese in stylo (R and R studio)

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm quite new to R and R studio, but I wanted to use the stylo package for stylometric analyses.

I collected two Chinese corpora in .txt, followed the instructions on https://sites.google.com/site/computationalstylistics/ , but neither R or R studio seemed to be able to read the Chinese text.

I know Chinese isn't one of the default supported languages of the stylo package, but [here](http://cls.ru.nl/~ihendrickx/Posters_ehum/4_Eder_Kestemont_Rybicki_Poster.pdf) they mentioned that results for Chinese and the stylo package are 'quite promising'.

Also, in R it doesn't seem to be able to type Chinese characters, but in R studio it does. Am I doing something wrong? I believe my encoding is in unicode.

I hope you can help me

Thomas

Comment: What is your default encoding and locale in R/Rstudio?

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you are using?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik My locale is: 
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Belgium.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Belgium.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Dutch_Belgium.1252


I tried to change it to a Chinese default one, hoping that would work, but I couldn't. I work in windows 7.

Comment: @nico I just set my working directory to a folder which holds a subfolder named 'corpus' (like the stylo manual says) and tried to use the stylo() function. This displays the GUI and although you can't select Chinese, one of the links posted above mentioned 'quite promising' results for Chinese - meaning it should be able to process my two test texts.